# python string split on pattern

Tags: python, string

I  have a long string to split.

```
 str1 = ' BATON ROUGE, LA -- Ascension, Assumption, East Baton Rouge, East Feliciana, Iberville, Livingston, Pointe Coupee, St. Helena, St. Mary, West Baton Rouge, West Feliciana Parishes, LA; Amite and Wilkinson Counties, MS. BEAUMONT-PORT ARTHUR, TX -- Hardin, Jasper, Jefferson, Newton, Orange,Tyler Counties, TX. '
```

expected outputs are:

```
sub1 = 'BATON ROUGE, LA -- Ascension, Assumption, East Baton Rouge, East Feliciana, Iberville, Livingston, Pointe Coupee, St. Helena, St. Mary, West Baton Rouge, West Feliciana Parishes, LA; Amite and Wilkinson Counties, MS.'
sub2 = 'BEAUMONT-PORT ARTHUR, TX -- Hardin, Jasper, Jefferson, Newton, Orange,Tyler Counties, TX.'
```

sub1 and sub2 contain   region name and state name  as well as  associated  county list.

If I split only  by'.' , there will be trouble that some county names also contain '.'.
How could I split on pattern, each sub1 or sub2 should end with state aberration and '.', like here 'MS.'  ,'TX.'?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Use `re.split` or `regex.split`.

Comment: Your data format has a serious flaw. It allows unquoted control characters (here: `.`) in the data. Your first task would be to find further edge cases in all the data and identify a pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import re
str1 = ' BATON ROUGE, LA -- Ascension, Assumption, East Baton Rouge, East Feliciana, Iberville, Livingston, Pointe Coupee, St. Helena, St. Mary, West Baton Rouge, West Feliciana Parishes, LA; Amite and Wilkinson Counties, MS. BEAUMONT-PORT ARTHUR, TX -- Hardin, Jasper, Jefferson, Newton, Orange,Tyler Counties, TX. '
new_data = re.split("(?<=\s[A-Z]{2})\.", str1)
print(new_data[0])
print(new_data[1])
```

Output:

```
BATON ROUGE, LA -- Ascension, Assumption, East Baton Rouge, East Feliciana, Iberville, Livingston, Pointe Coupee, St. Helena, St. Mary, West Baton Rouge, West Feliciana Parishes, LA; Amite and Wilkinson Counties, MS

BEAUMONT-PORT ARTHUR, TX -- Hardin, Jasper, Jefferson, Newton, Orange,Tyler Counties, TX
```

Regex explanation:

`\s[A-Z]{2}`: looks for double capital letter abbreviation i.e the state abbreviation proceeded by whitespace

`(?<=\s[A-Z]{2}\.` : positive look-behind, determines if `.` is preceded by the pattern above.